# How to get only names from find command without path

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to get only the names from the search result using find, but it always includes the directories too. How can I print only the names (or assign to a variable) using find

```
find trunk/messages/ -name "*.po" -printf '%f\n'
```

a similar command to assign this to a variable e.g. "resource" to use it later on.

EDIT: And if possible only the name excluding the extension.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `find trunk/messages/ -name "*.po" -exec basename {} .po \;`

Example and explanations:

Create some test files:

```
$ touch test1.po  
$ touch test2.po  
$ find . -name "*.po" -print
./test1.po  
./test2.po
```

Ok, files get found, including path.

For each result execute `basename`, and strip the .po part of the name

```
$ find . -name "*.po" -exec basename \{} .po \;  
test1  
test2
```

Comment: Great thanks :). Can I strip only the PO extension from dirs?

I mean: dir1/po1.po and dir2/po2.po can they be got like dir1/po1 and dir2/po2?

Comment: @user1754665 `find . -name '*.po' -exec bash -c 'echo ${0%.po}' {} \;`

Comment: @slhck thanks. lastly I need to get the filename without extension and the last folder where it is in: e.g: dir1/subdir1/subsubdir1/po1.po and dir2/subdir2/subsubdir2/po2.po should be set to a variable like: subsubdir1/po1 subsubdir2/po2, respectively.

Comment: @user1754665 Hmm, maybe `find . -name '*.po' -type f -exec sh -c 'echo $(basename $(dirname $0))/$(basename $0)' {} \;`

Comment: @Hennes What is the purpose of backslash before the opening curly brace in the last `find`?

Comment: The last example contains a stray backslash.

Comment: @wakeup you get what you want by combining @slhck's 2 comments because he forgot to strip the extension in the second one. but you can also use the built in function into `basename` for removing suffixes like `find trunk/messages/ -name "*.po" -exec sh -c 'echo "$(basename $(dirname $0))/$(basename -s ".po" $0)"' "{}" \;`.

Comment: **but** i personally would stick with a (slightly modified) version of his first comment with the *bash parameter expansion*, especially if you use `-iname` at `find` to not encounter problems because of case sensitivity: `find trunk/messages/ -iname "*.po" -exec bash -c 'echo "$(basename $(dirname $0))/$(basename ${0%.*})"' "{}" \;`

Answer (score 14):

You can use `-execdir` parameter which would print the file without path, e.g.:

```
find . -name "*.po" -execdir echo {} ';'
```

Files without extensions:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -execdir basename {} .po ';'
```

<sup>Note: Since it's not POSIX, BSD `find` will print clean filenames, however using GNU `find` will print extra `./`.</sup>

See: [Why GNU find -execdir command behave differently than BSD find?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/250191/21471)

Comment: This is the real answer. I need to do some work in "exec" already, so running basename doesn't fly.

Comment: The command will not print extra `./` in bash if `;` character is escaped by `\ `. Example: `'\;'`

Answer (score 2):

Based on a command I found here: http://www.unixcl.com/2009/08/remove-path-from-find-result-in-bash.html

You could do this using `sed` (which executed faster for me, than the `basename` approach):

```
find trunk/messages/ -name "*.po" | sed 's!.*/!!' | sed 's!.po!!'
```